# How to get a better understanding of a png representation on java?

Tags: java, image, png

I want to dive in the low level of how a png file is represented on memory in java, so that i can iterate over its pixels, change them, create a modified png file using existing one, etc.

Where do i begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could begin by reading it into a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with [`ImageIO.read(file)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) .
The [`getRGB(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) methods can help you to obtain information about the individual pixels, and the corresponding `setRGB(...)` methods help you to change them.

Answer (score 2):

The representation of an image in memory in Java, is essentially unrelated to the format of the file: be it PNG, JPEG, GIF or whatever, those are standards for encoding an image as a (language independent) stream of bytes. But when you are manipulating the pixels of an image in memory, you have already decoded it, and so you've "forgotten" from which format (PNG, JPEG...) it came from.

The most common way of manipulating an image in Java is using the  [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class, included in the *java.awt.image.** package. But that's not a requisite. For instance, I've worked on a low level PNG coder/encoder ([PNGJ](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/wiki/Overview)) that does not use BufferedImage, but instead gives you each image line as an `int[]` array.